# Node's path particle effect with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I'm working with Swift, Sprite Kit and Xcode 6,

I would like to create a particle effect in SpriteKit a little bit like the particles effects of the balls in the iOS game named "Duet", but I don't know how to proceed, I managed to create a particle effect, but not a particle like in this game who follows a node and draw the node's path...

Here is my code :

```
let firstCircle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
let particle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FirstParticle.sks")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    firstCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
    firstCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    particle.targetNode = firstCircle

    addChild(firstCircle)
    addChild(particle)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{        
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        firstCircle.position = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        firstCircle.position = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the emitter node's `targetNode` property to the node you want it to follow

Comment: I already did it, the particle is following my node but there isn't any "path" effect, like a trail

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I posted the essential part, not all of it because it's too long

Comment: what exactly is the problem

Comment: The particles appears on the node, but when I move the node there is no "dust particles", I don't know how to call that but I want the particles to trace the node's path.

Comment: In your scene's `didFinishUpdate` set the emitter's position to the position of the circle. Remove the one which sets the targetNode

Comment: I doubt that you can create that effect with particles.

Comment: Okapi, I tested what you said, but it doesn't make the result i wanted to, and @0x141E, if it's not possible with the particles effects, how could I manage to create an effect like the particles of the two balls in the game "Duet" ?

Comment: I have the same question. How can we create an effect like that in the game of Duet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To achieve a Duet like effect you need `particle` to be a child of the trailed node and `targetNode` set to the parent scene. `targetNode` controls which node the particles are rendered as a child of.

When `particle` is a child of the trailed node, it will emit particles with the trailed node as the origin. Changing `targetNode` to the parent scene leaves already emitted particles behind as the trailed node moves.

This code should work but you may need to fine tune `FirstParticle.sks`.

```
let firstCircle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
let particle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FirstParticle.sks")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    firstCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
    firstCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    particle.targetNode = self

    addChild(firstCircle)
    firstCircle.addChild(particle)
}
```

I was able to get a similar effect and ended up creating a Playground to demonstrate it. Check it out [here](https://github.com/dionlarson/Duet-Trail-Effect-SpriteKit-Playground).

[image: Demo of Duet trail effect]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know what configuration of the particle editor would give the particles (FirstParticle.sks) a look similar to the trail in duet? Thanks again.

Comment: See the edit. I uploaded a full Swift Playground demoing the effect. You can start with the particle sks files in there and modify them as needed.

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you have any issues with the playground.

Comment: @NoahCovey can you make sure to accept this answer for the bounty?

Comment: Just did! Thanks again